# Regex fail to get the stack trace

Tags: php, regex

I have a file with this structure:

```
[19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504] [info] system done. 
 0: array(
   'ID' => 'john foo'
 )

[19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482] [info] transaction done. 

[25-02-2016 10:44:16.132093] [error] Errore 
0: array(
      'Trace' => 'exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'primo_db.primo_userss' doesn't exist' in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\database.php:44
   Stack trace:
   #0 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\database.php(44): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM p...')
   #1 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\models\tests_model.php(31): Database->select('SELECT * FROM p...')
   #2 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\controllers\test.php(43): Tests_Model->selectData()
   #3 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\router.php(159): Test->selectUser()
   #4 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\map.php(52): Router->submit()
   #5 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\system\api.php(110): Map->init_get()
   #6 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\boot.php(21): Api->init()
   #7 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\index.php(18): Boot->__construct()
   #8 {main}'
   )
```

Now for the first two cases I have no problem for deserialize the structure as follow (the first two trace) the third trace isn't printed I put this in the example is the structure that I want to achieve:

```
"trace":[
{
    "date":"19-02-2016 16:57:17.104504",
    "type":"info",
    "message":"system done.",
    "ID":"john foo"
},
{
    "date":"19-02-2016 16:57:17.110482",
    "type":"info",
    "message":"transaction done.",
    "ID":""
 },
 { 
    "date":"25-02-2016 10:44:16.132093",
    "type":"error",
    "message" : "'exception 'PDOException' with message 
'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'primo_db.primo_userss' doesn't exist' in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\database.php:44"
    "stack": "#0 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\database.php(44): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM p...')
   #1 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\models\tests_model.php(31): Database->select('SELECT * FROM p...')
   #2 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\controllers\test.php(43): Tests_Model->selectData()
   #3 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\router.php(159): Test->selectUser()
   #4 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\core\map.php(52): Router->submit()
   #5 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\system\api.php(110): Map->init_get()
   #6 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\boot\boot.php(21): Api->init()
   #7 C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.5.29-1\apache2\htdocs\api\v1\index.php(18): Boot->__construct()
   #8 {main}'"
 }
]
```

but for the  `error` nothing is displayed 'cause the `regex` fail to deserialize the data. This is my code:

```
 $fh = file_get_contents($file);

 if(!$fh) { throw new Exception("Not found"); }

 $content = array(); 
 $content["trace"] = array();

 preg_match_all('/\[(.*)\][\s]*?\[(.*?)\][\s]*?(.*)[\s.]+(?:\d+[^\']*\'ID\'[ ]*=>[ ]*\'(.*)\')?/',
 $fh, $regs, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

 for($i = 0; $i < count($regs[0]); $i++)
 {
       $content['trace'][] = array(
       'date'    => $regs[1][$i],
       'type'    => trim($regs[2][$i]),
       'message' => trim($regs[3][$i]),
        'ID'      => trim($regs[4][$i]),
            );
  }

  return $content;
```

How I can fix this problem? 'Cause the `error` general  means that there is an array with the stack trace content..

Comment: You should show the result you want to obtain for the 3rd record.

Comment: the same structure, I just want get the `stack trace` and put it in a different index as `'Trace'      => trim($regs[some index][$i]),`

Comment: In this case write it in your post (as for the 2 previous records) since the structure you want in this case is unclear.

Comment: @anubhava: it isn't JSON, it's a log and he wants to obtain JSON.

Comment: @anubhava you have misunderstood the question. The `$content` contains a json. It's not my problem deserialize the json, I need to fix the regex for some type of content such as the trace (stack). Actually the system working but if there is content as I shown above the regex fail.

Comment: the third block show the structure of the stack trace that I want. Actually this block isn't printed

Comment: It is really very inconsistent structure because `system done` and  `transaction done` from previous entry are in output but `Errore` is not.

Comment: it's an typo error.. Anyway don't fix yourself on this, my is just an example.

Comment: Will [`/\[(?<date>[^]]*)\]\h*\[(?<type>[^]]*)\]\h*(?<msg>[^\r\n]*)(?:\R\h*\d+:\h*array(?<message>\((?:[^()]*|(?-1))*\)))?/s`](https://regex101.com/r/lL6mI1/1) work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this recursive pattern:

```
/\[(?<date>[^]]*)\]\h*\[(?<type>[^]]*)\]\h*(?<msg>[^\r\n]*)(?:\R\h*\d+:\h*array(?<message>\((?:[^()]*|(?-1))*\)))?/s
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lL6mI1/1)

**PS:** It will give extra `) 'Trace' => '` in last captured group, that you can remove with post processing.